# Как сделать чтобы файл проверил своё название

Tags: python

У меня есть файл main.py
Однако если его переименовать то файл потеряет большинство функций.

Comment: для этого есть переменная `__file__`

Comment: Какие именно функции он потеряет? Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы запускаете файл как `py` - достаточно переменной `__file__`.
Если вы собираетесь упаковывать свой `py` в `exe` - посмотрите в строну `sys.argv[0]`.